# JavaScript - pulling data from an array (currency conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

Evening all, (1st post so please be gentle as am new to all this (and coding itself)).

I am creating a currency conversion page for a small project. However I am having trouble getting data from the array to then multiply by user input. As a default I can get all currencies to a value of 1. i.e. GBP = 1 to USD = 1.3187.

I just cannot get the details to work with user input (prob very simple but am banging my head atm).

the array info appears like so. BRL: 2.4704, CAD: 0.97445

my code so far:

```
//FUNCTION
function currencyConvert() {
    var myCurrency = document.getElementById("currency").value; //selected user currency
    var conversion = document.getElementById("amount").value; //amount to be converted

    //AJAX API TO CHECK IF THERE IS INTERNET
    var myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //API ADDRESS
    var currData = "http://api.fixer.io/latest?" + "base=" + myCurrency;

    console.log(currData);

    myReq.open("GET", currData, true);
    //GET REQUEST TO SERVER
    myReq.send();

    myReq.onload = function() {
            //AJAX SERVER
            if (myReq.readyState == 4 && myReq.status == 200) {

                var result = myReq.responseText;
                /*console.log(myReq);*/
                console.log(result);

                //CONVERT JSON TO JAVASCRIPT
                var jsResult = JSON.parse(result);
                console.log(jsResult);

                /*var convertedRate = conversion * jsResult.rates
                console.log(convertedRate);*/

                //PULL BASE CURRENCY TO CHANGE FROM DROPDOWN

                /*var unitOne = jsResult.base;
                console.log(unitOne);*/

                /* jsResult.base = myCurrency;
                console.log(myCurrency);
                */
                //AMOUNT FROM USER INPUT BOX
                /*var amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;*/

                //CALCULATE THE INPUT BOX FOR BASE AGAINST CURRENCY CHOSEN
                /*console.log(myCurrency.rates);*/
                /*document.getElementById("converted").value = (unitOne*amount).toFixed(2);*/

                //DISPLAY CURRENCIES AGAINST BASE CURRENCY (CURRENT DEFAULT VALUE FROM AMOUNT =1)

                /*var conTotal = jsResult.rates*conversion;*/
                var conTotal = jsResult.rates;
                console.log(conTotal);



                document.getElementById('aud').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.AUD
                document.getElementById('cad').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.CAD
                document.getElementById('chf').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.CHF
                document.getElementById('cny').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.CNY
                document.getElementById('dkk').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.DKK
                document.getElementById('eur').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.EUR
                document.getElementById('gbp').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.GBP
                document.getElementById('hkd').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.HKD
                document.getElementById('huf').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.HUF
                document.getElementById('inr').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.INR
                document.getElementById('jpy').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.JPY
                document.getElementById('mxn').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.MXN
                document.getElementById('myr').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.MYR
                document.getElementById('nok').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.NOK
                document.getElementById('nzd').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.NZD
                document.getElementById('rub').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.RUB
                document.getElementById('sek').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.SEK
                document.getElementById('sgd').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.SGD
                document.getElementById('thb').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.THB
                document.getElementById('try').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.TRY
                document.getElementById('usd').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.USD
                document.getElementById('zar').innerHTML = jsResult.rates.ZAR

            } //end of if
        } //end of secondary function
} //end of main function*/
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. "I just cannot get the details to work with user input". I'm not clear what "cannot get the details to work"  means. Are there errors? If not, what is the result of the code, and what result are you expecting?

Comment: I ran the code myself, it appears to call the API successfully and console log the return data. Is it not displaying correctly on the front end? If so, perhaps show the HTML? Also, maybe try `document.getElementById('aud').html(jsResult.rates.AUD);`

Comment: I get no errors with the code. I just need to be able to multiply the code by the amount(value) the user inputs on the page. At present i can only display GBP = 1 against the other currencies. So if user wanted to see the rate of USD against £200 it remains at the default £1 conversion. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Here's live example code: http://plnkr.co/edit/r7opNoXYis4KcDD68TW7?p=preview